# Iterate across lines in two files in sequence

Tags: python

I have two files, and I want to perform some line-wise operation across both of them (one by one). I am now using two loops to achieve this. Is there a way to do it in a single loop (in python 2.7):

```
for fileName in [fileNam1,fileName2]:
    for line in open(fileName):
        do something
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been pointed out `itertools.chain` is an option, however there's also another useful standard module which avoids having to explicitly use `open`...

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']):
    print line
```

This also has some handy functions for line number and filename etc... Check the docs at http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html

**in reply to comments - using with a context manager**

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(fileinput.input(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'])) as infiles:
    for line in infiles:
        pass # stuff
```

Comment: +1 I like this better since the `itertools` solution will make it inconvenient to close the files.

Comment: In case the program ends abruptly, the next time I run it I get an `RuntimeError: input() already active`. Is there a way to get around this.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I am currently doing that. Is there a way to implement this in the code so that whenever it breaks the file get closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain) module has a tool for just that. Try this:

```
import itertools

for line in itertools.chain(open(file_name1), open(file_name2)):
    # do something
```

Comment: Although your solution do the job, I choose the `fileinput` solution as it closes the file after reading it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but the fileinput module may be useful.

```
"""Helper class to quickly write a loop over all standard input files.

Typical use is:

    import fileinput
    for line in fileinput.input():
        process(line)

This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:],
defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty.  If a filename is '-' it
is also replaced by sys.stdin.  To specify an alternative list of
filenames, pass it as the argument to input().  A single file name is
also allowed.

Functions filename(), lineno() return the filename and cumulative line
number of the line that has just been read; filelineno() returns its
line number in the current file; isfirstline() returns true iff the
line just read is the first line of its file; isstdin() returns true
iff the line was read from sys.stdin.  Function nextfile() closes the
current file so that the next iteration will read the first line from
the next file (if any); lines not read from the file will not count
towards the cumulative line count; the filename is not changed until
after the first line of the next file has been read.  Function close()
closes the sequence.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can avoid the inner loop using list comprehension or map, reduce,filter etc. It all depends on your need. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Those solutions will still involve loops also I would consider this more of a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer so please Sorry for any mistake

```
>>> file1 = open('H:\\file-1.txt')
>>> file2 = open('H:\\file-2.txt')
>>> for i, j in map(None, file1.readlines(), file2.readlines()):
        print i,j
```

Comment: -1 Not the question. Also `zip(*args)` > `map(None, *args)`. There is no need for `readlines`. `file` objects are iterators through lines of the file so you could simply do: `zip(file1, file2)`